# Proof Verification: A monotonically increasing sequence that is bounded above always has a LUB

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> Problem: Prove that a monotonically increasing sequence that is bounded above always has a least upper bound.

This theorem is present in calculus and real analysis books along with proofs for it. I want to know if my proof is convincing enough.

*Solution*: let's start with the definitions

> If $ \{a_n\} $ is monotonically increasing, then $ a_{n+1} \geq a_n $ for all $n$.
>
> If $ \{a_n\} $ is bounded above then there exists $M$ such that $a_n \leq M$ for all $n$.
>
> If $ M $ is an upper bound, but no number less than $ M $ is an upper bound for $ \{a_n\} $, then $ M $ is called the **least upper bound** for $ \{a_n\}$.

It has already been established in the previous exercise that if a monotonically increasing sequence $ \{a_n\} $ is bounded above, then the sequence converges to some value. Let's call this value of convergence $\ell$. Then

$$ lub\{a_n\} = max\{a_n\} = \ell = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n $$

For if $ \ell $ wasn't the least upper bound of $ \{a_n\} $ then $\{a_n\}$ wouldn't converge to it.

Comment: Well, for one it's not true that the $sup\{a_n\} = max\{a_n\}$, perhaps you meant that $sup\{a_n\}$ is an upper bound of $\{a_n\}$. Consider for example $\{a_n\} = arctan(n)$. The limit is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, but is not in $\{a_n\}$. ($Sup$ means supremum and is another word for least upper bound).

Comment: You mean $\lim_{n \to \infty} arctan(n) = \pi/2$ but $\pi/2$ isn't in $\{a_n\}$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @JackPfaffinger So even if a sequence is infinite, it is incorrect to say that the "infinitesimal" element is a part of the sequence?

Comment: I'm not completely certain what you mean here, but I think what you're asking is whether or not the limit of a sequence has to be contained in the sequence. The answer to that question is no, even if the sequence is infinite.

Comment: I mean: "$a_\infty$" isn't in $\{a_n\}_{1}^{\infty}$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89909/discussion-between-jack-pfaffinger-and-victor-s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not quite convincing enough for me. You didn't explicitly show why it was true. Let $L$ be the limit of the sequence $\{a_n\}$ We'll use the monotone convergence theorem as you said it was already proven to you. Clearly $L \geq a_n$ for all $n$. And so $L$ is an upper bound.

Assume there is some upper bound which is less than $L$, call it $k$. Let $L - k = p$. From the definition of the limit of a sequence, there exists an $N$ such that for all $n > N$, $|a_n - L| < \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon > 0.$ Now take $\varepsilon = p$. This shows that there is a term which is greater than $k$, contradicting the choice of $k$ as an upper bound.

Now we have shown  that $L$ is a upper bound, and any value smaller than $L$ is not an upper bound, finishing the proof.

Comment: Check your arithmetic again.

Comment: Wow.. that was embarassing.

Comment: One thing I noticed. You defined $L = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$. Then you concluded that $sup(a_n) = L$. So $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L = sup \{a_n\}$. I wanted to show the same thing. So your assessment is not that my conclusion is incorrect, but that my method is incorrect in the sense that I didn't really show it.

Comment: Yeah when you said "For if $ℓ$ wasn't the least upper bound of ${a_n}$ then ${a_n}$ wouldn't converge to it." That statement was true, however the problem then becomes to prove that statement is in fact true.

Comment: This is the most correct answer here. It is logically well stated, but lacks more formal statements that should be given with the proof.

Answer (score -1):

*My Approach-*

Let M be the LUB of {$x_n$}.
Then $x_n \in N_ε(M)$ for some $n\in S\forall  ε>0$ ,(i. e.$x_n \in N_ε(M)$ when $K\leq n\leq s^ * $ , where $K:=inf S , s^ *:=sup S$).Here S is an interval in $\Bbb R$ ,such that $infS,supS\in\Bbb N$.

But let $\exists k>s^*=supS$ such that $x_k \notin N_ε(M).(\therefore k>n)$

$\implies x_n>x_k$,viz. a contradiction. $^. .^. (x_n)$ is monotonically increasing.

$\therefore \nexists k\in\Bbb N :k>s^*$ for which $x_k \notin N_ε(M) \forall ε>0$.

$\implies \forall ε>0 ,\exists K $ such that $x_n\in N_ε(M) \forall n\geq K.$

Hence {$x_n$}$\to M$. ■

Comment: You cannot assume something that you need to prove in the question.

Comment: So , can I approach like, suppose ${x_n}$ has no LUB... and proceed ?